# CodeIgniter just simple URl Rewrite friendlyurl

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting

Hello I have tried everywhere and i have a part solution:(

I have this kind of URL

http://www.somesite.com/about?koje=gore

The original is

http://www.somesite.com/index.php/drey/about?koje=gore

Added 
.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on URL rewriting
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And removed index.php

Added

```
$route['default_controller'] = "drey";
$route["about"] = 'drey/about';
```

And remove contoller, now i have problem i want to get this kind of link

```
http://www.somesite.com/gore.html
```

Is it possible to do that in routes.php?

Comment: Very close :((  $route['(:any)'] = "drey/about";

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into **config.php** and write

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';
```

You need to remember, that in order for you to have .html suffix, you will need to create your links with CI URL helper. More info at [CodeIgniter URLs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) and [URL Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Comment: I dont want to to that, i want to hide the function name, and GET['koje'], just to have value od GET['koje'] :)